# How to formulate IRR(excel formula - 1+IRR(F10:F22)^12-1) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2014, sql-server-2014-express

How to formulate IRR(excel formula - 1+IRR(F10:F22)^12-1) in SQL Server

What I need to add is IRR based on M0 to M60 columns.

Expected Result :

IRR = 24.24%

I've tried several code but it's not working.
I try an IRR function that looks like this:
[T-SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF2Yw.jpg)